# Сослаться на наследуемый метод

Tags: java

Я написал метод Sgod переопределил его в другом классе, а потом переопределил еще раз при создании объекта. Могу ли я из кода обьекта вызвать самую первую функцию

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class obj = new Class() {
            public void Sgod() {
                super.Sgod();
            }
        };
    }
    public void Sgod() {}
}

public class Class extends Main {
    public Class() {
        Sgod();
    }

    @Override
    public void Sgod() {}
}
```

Comment: нет. если вам нужен метод родителя родителя (дедушки) - значит у вас косяк с иерархией наследования.

Comment: Старые ответы на основном SO: [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри класса `Class` вы можете вызвать метод `Sgod()` родительского класса так: `super.Sgod()` , в остальных случаях Java не подразумевает такое в отличии от C++ например.

Comment: Да это понятно, было интересно узнать могу ли из кода объекта